# How to filter youtrack issues by vcs change number

Tags: svn, youtrack

A tester asked me to find youtrack issues that have svn checkin number: 11573.

Problem is, I cant seem to filter by vcs changes:
vcs changes:11573
vcs changes:-11573
etc.
return all issues.

Is it possible to filter issues by vcs change number, or is this done in upsource/other product?

Thanks

ps using YouTrack (6.5 Build 16807) and SVN 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there's no such search in YouTrack. Try going from TeamCity side, i.e. find a revision there and see which issues it mentions.